# Write data from `FileContentResult`

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm processing multiple pdf files, so data from each file is stored in a list of `FileContentResult`. I can't figure out how to write this data into pdf files again. My work is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Job newJob)
{
    string path = MyServer.MapPath(@"\Files\");
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    List<FileContentResult> fileContentResults = new List<FileContentResult>();
    foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(file.FullName))
        {
            var sourceFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file.FullName); 
            var outputStream = new MemoryStream(); //make memorystream
            var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFileStream), new PdfWriter(outputStream)); 
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, false); // create pdf document with form
            IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetAllFormFields();
            if (fields != null)
            {
                //Populate fields...
            }
                pdf.Close();
                byte[] bytes = outputStream.ToArray();
                fileContentResults.Add(File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, file.FullName));
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (var file in fileContentResults)
    {
        //I do not know how to write from FileContentResult(file) to a pdf file and add this pdf file to a zip folder
    }
    return View();
}
```

I cant figure out how to write data from `FileContentResult` to create pdf file and then add this file to a zip folder. I've tried looking on the web but couldn't find anything very helpful.

Comment: Writing into a zip file is a somewhat different question, but do you know how to write a byte array to a file? If so, can't you just use the `FileContents` and `FileDownloadName` properties from each `FileContentResult`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for replying. I do not know how to write a byte array to a file using `FileContents` and `FileDownloadName` properties from `FileContentResult`. I will really appreciate it if you could please demonstrate or refer me to a weblink for this as well as writing into a zip file question.

Comment: Firstly, each post should be about *one* thing. It shouldn't be about both "writing arbitrary data to a file" *and* "creating a zip file". Secondly, you should separate concerns. If someone handed you a `byte[]` would you know how to write that to a file? If so, what does it matter whether you obtained the `byte[]` from a `FileContentResult` or not? (Hint: you should research how to write data to a file, and how to create a zip file. Neither of those tasks are specific to where the data comes from.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Understood your points. Thank you, Sir. On my way to research.

Comment: Also why save the Zip to a file, you could just as well save it to a `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string zipPath = MyServer.MapPath(@"\Files\MyZip.zip"); // Path for the zip file
using (var zipArchive = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var archive = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(zipArchive, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (var fileContent in fileContentResults)
        {
            string pdfFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileContent.FileDownloadName); 
            string pdfFilePath = MyServer.MapPath($@"\Files\{pdfFileName}"); 

            // Write the PDF file
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilePath, fileContent.FileContents);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pdfFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            {
                fileStream.Write(fileContent.FileContents, 0, fileContent.FileContents.Length);
            }
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(pdfFilePath, pdfFileName);
        }
    }
}

// Return the ZIP file as a download (if needed)
byte[] zipBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(zipPath);
return File(zipBytes, "application/zip", "MyZip.zip");
```

first write the byte array from each `FileContentResult` to individual PDF files on the server. Then, use `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` to create a ZIP file and add all the newly created PDF files to this ZIP archive. This approach will allow you to convert your list of `FileContentResult` objects into a single downloadable ZIP file containing all the PDFs.

Comment: @Xs_ i have modifed the code by using statement that will close the file stream. after saving i hope this works.

Comment: @Xs_ note that there is no reason to read the whole file into memory you can just pass a path to file to [corresponding overload of `File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-file(system-string-system-string-system-string-system-nullable((system-datetimeoffset))-microsoft-net-http-headers-entitytagheadervalue-system-boolean)) method. Or perform all computations in memory (depending on the case).